# snowflake move table from one schema to another

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two databases:

```
DB1:
  SCHEMA1:
     -- TABLE1
     -- TABLE2


DB2:
  SCHEMA2:
```

I want to move `TABLE1` to `DB2::SCHEMA2`

i.e

```
DB1:
  SCHEMA1:
     -- TABLE2


DB2:
  SCHEMA2:
     -- TABLE1
```

also note in future i may delete `DB1`

Answer (score 2):

I could do this

```
  alter table if exists "DB1"."SCHEMA1"."TABLE1" RENAME TO "DB2"."SCHEMA2"."TABLE1";
```

Answer (score 1):

I have to correct myself because Snowflake starts supporting renaming a table to another database/schema.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table.html#parameters